# Bidirectional A* (A-star) Search

Tags: algorithm, shortest-path

I'm implementing a bidirectional A* search (bidirectional as in the search is performed from both the origin and destination simultaneously, and when these two searches meet, I'll have my shortest path - at least with a bit of extra logic thrown in).

Does anyone have any experience with taking a unidirectional A* and bidirectionalising(!) it - what sort of performance gain can I expect?  I'd reckoned on it more-or-less halving the search time, at a minimum - but may I see bigger gains that this?  I'm using the algorithm to determine shortest routes on a road network - if that's in any way relevant (I've read about MS's "Reach" algorithm, but want to take baby-steps towards this rather than jumping straight in).

Comment: Note - question title repeats A* in word-form to ease searching.

Comment: FYI: here is a link to the MS paper on Reach for A* (A-star): http://www.avglab.com/andrew/pub/alenex06.pdf

Comment: @shindigo, the link looks like dead. Is it the same paper? http://www.cs.tau.ac.il/~haimk/papers/alenex06.pdf Reach for A∗: Efficient Point-to-Point Shortest Path Algorithms by Andrew V. Goldberg, Haim Kaplan, Renato F. Werneck?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the best possible case it'd run in O(b^(n/2)) instead of O(b^n), but that's only if you're lucky :)

(where b is your branching factor and n is the number of nodes a unidirectional A* would consider)

It all depends on how easily the two searches meet, if they find each other at a good halfway point early in the search you've done away with a lot of search time, but if they branch into wildly different directions you may end up with something slower than simple A* (because of all the extra bookkeeping)

Comment: Thanks Michael - some additional research has shown that I'm unlikely to be lucky - bidirectional A* is purportedly quite awkward when it comes to both directions converging on the same node.  I may give it a go, or more likely will invest some time in figuring out Reach.

Comment: On bigger numbers, you clearly win when doing bi-directional search. Microsoft Research labs use this algorithm, but with a lot of more complicated improvements.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to try https://github.com/sroycode/tway
there is a benchmarking script that compares this with standard astar
( for NY city roads data it seems to give a 30% time benefit )

Answer (score 1):

You may consider clustering as much more efficient booster. Also see [this article](http://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-speed-up-a-pathfinding-with-the-jump-point-search-algorithm--gamedev-5818)